# What is the cause of kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException exceptions in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka Mirrormaker to simulate production traffic to an Elastic MapReduce cluster running Spark.  Here is my setup:

1) One instance of Kafka Mirrormaker consumes from the production Kafka instance and populates a test Kafka instance

2) A second instance of Kafka Mirrormaker consumes from the test Kafka instance created in 1) and publishes to a new Kafka cluster

3) The Elastic MapReduce cluster consumes from the Kafka cluster in 3).

The issue is that I am seeing kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException errors in my log files.  I was wondering how to prevent these from occurring.

This is the procedure I use when running my EMR job:

1) Kill my running Mirrormaker

2) Drop all topics on the cluster

3) Create all topics

4) Restart Mirrormaker

5) Start the EMR job

Previously, I thought that the kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException occurred because I was replacing the hosts.  However, even after dropping/recreating topics, I still get the error.

Is there a particular setting I need to make on either my Mirrormaker or the Kafka cluster to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker does only replicate messages from one cluster to another, but not offsets. Internally, MirrorMaker uses consumers and producers. This implies, that the message offsets in the target cluster will be different. Assume you have a topic in the source cluster and retention delete some data already, and thus, the oldest offset is 1000 and you create a new topic in the target cluster. Message 1000 from the source cluster will have offset 0 in the target cluster.

You will need to "translate" the offsets manually. For example, you can get the beginning offsets before you start the replication with MirrorMaker and subtract the number for the offset in the target cluster.